# Have LDAP Search Return a 1 if a record is found

Tags: bash, ldap, ldap-query, return-code

Hello again Stackoverflow,

Is there a method to have ldapsearch return a "1" if a single record is found, 0 if no record is found or 2(or larger) if multiple records are found in ldap.  I would like to be able to test for the record, and if a 1 is returned, then take some predefined action.  I know I can set $something=0 then do a ldapsearch >> $something and then test if $something!=0 but this will not be an efficient use of memory or process time and may lead to unexpected "fun" in my script. This would also require extra tests to be performed against $something that will add more time to the batch job.

ldapsearch -LLL -h ds389.some.org -p 389 -D "uid=someAdmin,o=some.org" -w *SOMEpassWord* -b "ou=People,o=some.org" -s sub '(&(RMailAliases=zzz)(!(RMid=d*)))'

Comment: If it isn't mentioned in the documentation, no.

Comment: thank you for you input.  You are correct that there is no documented method.  I flagged a valid answer if your interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` echo `ldapsearch -LLL -h ds389.some.org -p 389 -D "uid=someAdmin,o=some.org" -w SOMEpassWord -b "ou=People,o=some.org" -s sub '(&(RMailAliases=zzz)(!(RMid=d*)))' dn | grep dn: | wc -l` `` should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you sir.  nothing like grepping for the common response on all records and then counting it!  thank you

Comment: Cool answer even if it is still true that LDAP can not return a 1 or 0 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Shockingly, ldapsearch (as of 2.4.44) does not return a non-zero result on a non-match event. From the man-page:

> DIAGNOSTICS
>      Exit  status  is  zero  if  no errors occur.  Errors result in a non-zero exit status and a diagnostic message written to standard error.

Given the age of this product, it's unlikely this will ever change.

A reasonable solution is provided by @heiglandreas, but it could be better:

```
ldapsearch -LLL <ldap-connection-options <ldap-search-query> dn |
grep -q ^dn:
```

The `dn` attribute is output by ldapsearch regardless, so specifying it minimizes its output, while the `-LLL` option suppresses superfluous output by ldapsearch. The `-q` option of POSIX grep ensures the entire pipeline exits with non-zero if no match is found.

If you need the result as a text string, simply do `echo $?` after the above. Alternatively, you could replace the grep with `grep -c ^dn:` which will output `1` if found and `0` if not found.

Comment: To make this more googleable: this is useful to implement a Docker health check for OpenLDAP containers.